# How can I get the workplace location path?

Tags: java, path, workspace

I have tried getting my project workspace absolute path, but I only could get the path through eclipse or tomcat..
I need the actual path where the project files are located, such as:

```
"C:\Users\Annie\workspace-java\ProfessionalsWeb"
('ProfessionalsWeb' is my project's name)
```

or to simplify my question- even the path where "WebContent" folder inside my project in java workplace is located.

that is why those options are NOT good for me:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir"); 
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath();
```

which give me:

```
"C:\eclipse"
"/C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/lib/"
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

If you need this in a servlet then use

`getServletContext().getRealPath("/")`

Comment: Tnx!!!
that's what I'm getting:
"C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\wtpwebapps\ProfessionalsWeb\ "
What am I missing..
all my files are located at both places.
is my project should be located inside tomcat folder and not inside java workspace?
I'm confused..

and yes.. I need this through Servet.

Comment: Your welcome :). If this answer is what you are looking for, I think you can accept it. Therefore other persons can use and it can be help to others.